# Faint Boxes in JPG Images Appearing

Tags: wordpress, image, compression, jpeg, photo

Having some issues on my Wordpress installation.
I'm noticing that on some monitors faint/semi-opaque boxes are appearing in my JPG images.
I didn't notice this until I was viewing my website on a friend's computer.
They aren't appearing on the original images, just when they are uploaded to my server and WP displays them.

I am about to add a filter changing the jpeg compression quality to 100%, rather than 90%, but before I go and re-upload all of my images, have any of you guys experienced this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean a box like a border around the image, or an overlay on top of the image? Also is it appearing only on the webpage, or also when you look at the images on the server?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a response sensitivity problem in the monitors. Is it any particular brand of monitor?

Other things could contribute to the problem.

Your images may subsample the Cb and Cr components and your JPEG decoder may not be evening out the subsampled components. get a JPEG dumping program and see if the sampling rates are higher for Y than Cb and Cr.

You image may be over-quantized (quality).